# Discrete math: Group: why powers defined for integer, not member of the group?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I could not find the answer by web search.
I was surprised reading in [wiki: Discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm):

> In the mathematics of the real numbers, the logarithm $\log_b a$ a is a
>   number x such that $b^x$ = a, for given numbers a and b. Analogously, in
>   any group G, powers $b^k$ can be defined for all integers k, and the
>   discrete logarithm $\log_b a$ a is an integer k such that $b^k$ = a.

Is it a most widely accepted definition of powers? I wonder why in definition *integer* term is used, not said: powers $b^k$ can be defined for all k which is a member of group G?

What would be implications of such change?

ADDED after some answers:

As I understand now the question is about definition and also naming, if we define some operation, can we call it an [exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)? Wiki page on that term is so long... maybe I will add more of my thoughts on this matter here later.

Comment: How do you understand $b^k$ to be defined for a group?

Comment: Unless you are asking about the implications of an actual, specific definition, your question is too vague and not really about mathematics. If you had a proposed definition for $b^k$, that would be a different thing.

Answer (score 1):

Take the cyclic group of order 2: $C_2 = \{1, a\}$, with $a^2 = 1$.
How would you define $a^{1/2}$? It should be some element $b$ such that $b^2 = a$, right? However $1^2 = 1$ and $a^2 = 1$, so there is no solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The set of $2\times 2$ matrices of real numbers forms a group under matrix multiplication.

How would you evaluate this exponentiation of a matrix by a matrix?
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}
^{\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 6 \\ 7 & 8 \end{pmatrix}} .$$

One the other hand we easily understand how to do this one:
$$ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}
^{5}, $$
because this just tells us to perform the already-defined group operation
(in this case, matrix multiplication) on a certain number of copies of the given matrix.
Moreover, applying the group operation repeatedly with copies of the same element turns out to be a thing we might like to do often, so it's a useful definition.

Answer (score 1):

For x a member of a group (with multiplicative notation) and n a positive integer, x^n can be defined recursively.  Define x^1= x and then define x^(k+1)= x(x^k).  Since groups have inverses, we can extend that definition to all integers. x^0= group identity and x^(-n)= (x^(-1))^n, but, as J.-E. Pin indicated, we may not be able to extend beyond the integers.